# Get PID for subprocesses for asynchronous futures in R shiny

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny-server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  out1_rows <- reactiveVal()

   observeEvent(input$run1, {
   prog <- Progress$new(session)
   prog$set(message = "Analysis in progress",
         detail = "This may take a while...",
         value = NULL)

  fut1 = future({
  system(paste("Command1" , input$file ">", "out1.txt"))

  system(paste("Command2" , out1.txt ">", "out2.txt"))
  head_rows <- read.delim("out2.txt")
    return(head_rows)
    }) %...>%
     out1_rows() %>%
  finally( ~ prog$close())
NULL
})


 observeEvent(req(out1_rows()), {
 output$out_table <-
  DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(
    out1_rows(),
    )
  ))

observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    async_pid <- fut1$job$pid  ##this is empty
    #async_pid <- Sys.getpid()  ##this return PID for main process and kills "/opt/shiny-server/R/SockJSAdapter.R"  but not for subprocesses inside future()
    system(paste("kill -15", async_pid))
  })
}
```

Here, i would need to kill the process running the commands inside future(). I tried in the above way to fetch the PID running the future() process and kill when `input$cancel` is triggered. However, `fut1$job$pid` is not returning any PID value and hence the kill operation is not successful.

This link [from future vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html) shows how to fetch PID for future() jobs. However, in my case i am not able to use `Sys.getpid()` inside future() as i am not sure how to store the PID value as the process is already returning some output from my system commands.

This page [future GIT](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/93) shows an alternate way of External Kill with the syntax `fut1$job$pid`. But this fails to fetch the PID.

I couldn't figure this out after trying different ways or blinded with the syntax. Could someone hint the way to do this.

Comment: Besides a full reproducible example you should add the 'shiny' tag.

Comment: I wonder if any of the people upvoting this question actually tried to execute the above code.
For sure, in R async is an interesting topic, but should we really encourage others to ask their questions this way?

Answer (score 3):

Can you please provide us with a full reproducible example?

You might want to have a look at library([future.callr](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.callr)):

using `plan(callr)` you can get the pid and kill the process like this:

```
library(future)
library(promises)
library(future.callr)

plan(callr)

myFuture <- future({
  Sys.sleep(5)
  return(runif(1))
})

myFuture$process$get_pid()
myFuture$process$is_alive()

# myFuture$process$kill()
# myFuture$process$is_alive()

then(myFuture, onFulfilled = function(value){
print(value)
}, onRejected = NULL)
```

**Edit** - adapted from your code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(future)
library(promises)
library(future.callr)
library(shinyjs)
library(V8)

plan(callr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Trigger & kill future"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId="run1", label="run future"),
      actionButton(inputId="cancel", label="kill future")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('out_table')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  disable("cancel") 
  out1 <- reactiveValues(rows=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$run1, {

    disable("run1")
    enable("cancel")
    out1$rows <- NULL

    prog <- Progress$new(session)
    prog$set(message = "Analysis in progress",
             detail = "This may take a while...",
             value = NULL)

    fut1 <<- future({
      # system(paste("Command1" , input$file, ">", "out1.txt"))
      # system(paste("Command2" , out1.txt, ">", "out2.txt"))
      # head_rows <- read.delim("out2.txt")
      head_rows <- data.frame(replicate(5, sample(runif(20, 0, 1), 20, rep=TRUE)))
      Sys.sleep(5)
      return(head_rows)
    })

    print(paste("Running async process with PID:", fut1$process$get_pid()))

    then(fut1, onFulfilled = function(value){
      out1$rows <<- value
    }, onRejected = function(error){NULL})

    finally(fut1, function(){
      prog$close()
      disable("cancel")
      enable("run1")
    })

    return(NULL)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)


  observeEvent(req(out1$rows), {
    output$out_table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(out1$rows))
  })

  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    async_pid <- fut1$process$get_pid()
    print(paste("Killing PID:", async_pid))
    # system(paste("kill -9", async_pid)) # Linux - kill
    # system(paste("taskkill /f /pid", async_pid)) # Windows - kill
    fut1$process$kill() # library(future.callr) - kill
    out1$rows <- NULL
    disable("cancel")
    enable("run1")
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Errors occuring occasionally:

```
Unhandled promise error: callr failed, could not start R, exited with non-zero status, has crashed or was killed 
Warning: Error in : callr failed, could not start R, exited with non-zero status, has crashed or was killed 
  95: <Anonymous>
```

Maybe this [statement](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/93#issuecomment-294228443) from @HenrikB tells us what we are running into:

> However, to get this working properly you probably also need to make
>   your future expression / future code interrupt aware using
>   withCallingHandlers() etc. It'll also unknown to me what happens if
>   you signal too many interrupts in a row - it might be that you manage
>   to interrupt the main R-loop of the worker, which then will cause the
>   R worker to terminate. That'll result in a missing R worker and you've
>   got that problem you mention at the beginning.

The error is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/r-lib/callr#tips) but currently in the future.callr-context I don't know how to work around it.

**2nd Edit:**
By now I got some further [feedback](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/93#issuecomment-445396402) from Henrik Bengtsson. He once again mentions that the core future API currently **isn't supporting the termination of futures**. So, in the end no matter what backend we use, we might run into problems.

Disregarding this info, I'd have another look at the `library(ipc)` [vignette](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fellstat/ipc/blob/master/inst/doc/shinymp.html) which provides two examples on the topic *Killing a long running process*. But I pointed to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53005788/9841389) already - which probably led to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151431/r-shiny-future-planmultiprocess-planmulticore-kill-long-running-process).

In the end all of this might be useless regarding your scenario because you are using `system()` calls which create subprocesses of their own (and have their own pid accordingly). Therefore why don't you use `wait = FALSE` in your system command (as I mentioned in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863720/async-display-progress-when-actionbutton-is-hit-and-disable-other-operations-fo/) already) to get your async behaviour and catch their pid using something like `myCommand & echo $!` (see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process)). This way you don't need any futures.

Comment: The problem here is my future function has a promise `%...>%` and so assigning `myFuture<-future()` is not working. Would be great if you could re-check my OP how future is giving a promise out. I have some illustration here as well https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/93 .

Comment: it is a bit hard to get reprod example in this case.

Comment: You don't need that promise. You can e.g. retrieve the result of you future via a call to `then` (see my edit) and wrap it in an observer in the shiny context.

Comment: The OP returns the reactive value `out1_rows` from the future and `observeEvent` is triggered to render the value of the reactive output as datatable (see edit). I am now skeptical in using `then` in this scenario. Probably i am not seeing what you are saying. Is it possible to imbed the code you are trying to reach for my example code in the OP?

Comment: I took some time and made a rep. example from your code (which includes unclosed brackets and missing commas. You really should spend more time on preparing your questions, so more people are willing to deal with them). It explains my idea of using `then`. I used `reactiveValues` so you can add more outputs. Unfortunately the killing of the process doesn't work in a clean way (errors occuring). Please try both kill-methods `system()` / `fut1$process$kill()` on your Linux machine and let me know if you get the same errors (I'm currently on a Windows system).

Answer (score 0):

Could find the PID by insetring `cat()` as such:

```
future({
   
   cat('future process PID \n', Sys.getpid(), '\')

   <expensive operation>

})
```

the PID number will appear in console when running the app. This is how I have found out that, in my case, the PID outside and inside the future were identical.